# Discord.py Getting a number of messages deleted from audit log

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a logging system with discord.py. For now, I'm trying to get the number of messages were deleted from a single audit log entry (since sometimes the audit logs updates an entry instead of creating a new one), so I tried with "entry.action.count". Here's my code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def deletecount(ctx):
    async for entry in ctx.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        print(entry.action.count)
```

But instead of printing the number of messages deleted, it just prints

```
<built-in method count of _EnumValue_AuditLogAction object at 0x000001FF9769C640>
```

From this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5eqy.png), in this case the latest entry has 5 deleted messages. I'm trying to print out that "5". So how do I get the number of message deleted from the latest audit log entry? The documentation doesn't have further information on how to use the extra attribute for entry.action.

I should also add that I have asked someone about this, they suggested to try `print(entry.action.count())`, but I got

```
TypeError: tuple.count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

What is the argument that should be given there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, use the `extra` attribute and it will return a dict with the data you want (the docs don't give you a lot of information about it because the return value differs from the type of action):

```py
async for entry in ctx.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_bulk_delete):
    count = entry.extra['count']
```

The return value of `AuditLogEntry.extra` varies depending on the type of event, the example above will only work with `message_bulk_delete`

*PS: You were using the wrong `action` in the iterator, it should be `AuditLogAction.message_bulk_delete` not `AuditLogAction.message_delete`*

#### References:

- [`AuditLogEntry.extra`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AuditLogEntry.extra)

Comment: I got it now. Although not necessarily the same as your answer, but your answer did help a lot in figuring out how to use the attribute. Turns out, the proper way to use the attribute is `entry.extra.count`. Also, it did work for `AuditLogAction.message_delete` as well along with `AuditLogAction.message_bulk_delete`. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm happy to help, the `entry.action` attribute returned me a dict like this: `{"count": "5"}`, it's weird that you got another thing...